# Where is the apps link assistant in Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-links

I'm on Android Studio Chipmunk and cannot find the app links assistant anywhere. All tutorials say it's under the tools menu, but it's not there. Has it been removed?

Comment: It's there for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q1YA.png. Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2

Comment: I wonder if this is happening only on mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Search "Links Assistant" in actions and turn on the plugin.
Then go to Tools > App Links Assistant
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXqN3.png)